# She and I "had" or "have" lots of trips together?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, word-usage

Which one has the correct verb usage?

1. She and I had lots of trips together.
2. She and I have had lots of trips together.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this. Both are grammatical. Which best expresses your thought depends on what that thought is.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct. The first one talks about what happened in the past and the other one talks about what happened in the past with a connection to the present moment.

Consider these examples:

> She and I had lots of trips together **when we were young**.
>
> She and I have had lots of trips together **during this past year**.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, they are both correct. The first sentence is the simple past tense (the action has happened and now it's over).  The second is an example of the present perfect

"The present perfect is used to indicate a link between the present and the past. The time of the action is before now but not specified, and we are often more interested in the result than in the action itself."

Examples:

An action or situation that started in the past and continues in the present. I have lived in Bristol since 1984 (= and I still do.)

An action performed during a period that has not yet finished. She has been to the cinema twice this week (= and the week isn't over yet.)

A repeated action in an unspecified period between the past and now. We have visited Portugal several times.

An action that was completed in the very recent past, expressed by 'just'. I have just finished my work.

An action when the time is not important. He has read 'War and Peace'. (= the result of his reading is important)

http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/

Comment: Not a question suitable for ELU.

Comment: No.............

Comment: It sends a wrong signal to the user-base when such basic questions are rewarded with an answer. These questions belong on websites aimed at more basic questions, where they're fine.